# Jinja Template for Elasticsearch Beats

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible, jinja2

I am creating an Ansible role to deploy Elastic Stack and various Beats.  I have all my ES servers up and running and now working on the deployment of the various Beats that I need.

I am creating a Jinja template for the beats config yaml files.  I need to identify my ingest nodes and port.  I am deploying everything from Foreman, so I am using parameters there to override the defaults that are set in my roles.

I have an array variable setup like this:  `ingest_nodes: ["node1", "node2", "node3"]`
I have the same thing setup for master_nodes.  To get that array in the template for the elasticsearch.yml file template I use `{{ master_nodes|to_yaml }}` and this produces the results I need in this file.

But for the beats config file, it looks like I need to append the port (which I have defined as a variable as well) to each node.

I'm looking for a way to do this in the template.  I have done it this way to make the cluster scalable.  If I need more ingest nodes, or what ever kind of nodes, I just add the host name to the appropriate array variable, build out the new VM and re-run the ansible on all nodes to get the updated configs.

From the below variables:

```
ingest_nodes: ["node1", "node2", "node3"]
elastic_port: 9200
```

I need to be able to have the template output like this:

```
host: [node1:9200, node2:9200, node3:9200]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task below

```
    - template:
        src: beats.conf.j2
        dest: beats.conf
```

with the template

```
shell> cat beats.conf.j2
host: [{% for item in ingest_nodes-%}
{{ item }}:{{ elastic_port }}{{ ", " if not loop.last else "" }}
{%- endfor %}]
```

gives

```
shell> cat beats.conf
host: [node1:9200, node2:9200, node3:9200]
```